# Smart relay setup on the locally running SMTP server

Tags: smtp, jelastic

Jelastic runs an SMTP server on a node. Does Jelastic, as a policy, allow setting up a smart relay on the local SMTP server?

I understand that some sysadmin from the service provider would need to do that on a per node basis. In my case, EverData is the service provider and their sysadmin says Jelastic policies don't allow such a change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Elastic VPS or Docker node types to run and configure whatever you want (you have full root access). The only limitation is the provider's AUP.